# LiteIDE for Go in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, liteide

It seems to me that LiteIDE is a good environment to get started with Go...

But in order to debug, it's asking me for the following:

[image: LiteIDE External Applications Settings]

What should I set these to if I'm developing a Google App Engine app?

I need the ability to detect and give hints to compile-time errors in the IDE. That should also be the case when using GAE-specific APIs (Channel API, etc.)

Though for runtime errors, I would assume that those are better left to visiting the dev site.

In other words- the way Google App Engine does things if I understand correctly, is you launch dev_appserver.py and then you don't actually recompile/relaunch again, the dev server does all of that and you simply visit http://localhost:8080 to test it, and it will give runtime errors descriptively in the browser.